# Extract string between prefix and suffix

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have these columns:

```
                 text.NANA text.22 text.32
1    Female RNDM_MXN95.tif      No      NA
12     Male RNDM_QOS38.tif      No      NA
13  Female  RNDM_WQW90.tif      No      NA
14    Male  RNDM_BKD94.tif      No      NA
15    Male  RNDM_LGD67.tif      No      NA
16   Female RNDM_AFP45.tif      No      NA
```

I want to create a column that only has the barcode that starts with `RNDM_` and ends with `.tif`, but not including `.tif`. The tricky part is to get rid of the gender information that is also in the same column. There are a random amount of spaces between the gender information and the `RNDM_`:

```
                 text.NANA text.22 text.32    BARCODE
1    Female RNDM_MXN95.tif      No      NA RNDM_MXN95
12     Male RNDM_QOS38.tif      No      NA RNDM_QOS38
13  Female  RNDM_WQW90.tif      No      NA RNDM_WQW90
14    Male  RNDM_BKD94.tif      No      NA RNDM_BKD94
15    Male  RNDM_LGD67.tif      No      NA RNDM_LGD67
16   Female RNDM_AFP45.tif      No      NA RNDM_AFP45
```

I made a very poor attempt with this, but it didn't work:

```
dfrm$BARCODE <- regexpr("RNDM_", dfrm$text.NANA)
# [1] 8 6 9 7 7 8 9 9 8 8 9 9 6 6 7 8 9 8
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to remove the ".tif" from the text.NANA column or is it more complicated ? If not it might be easier to use `substr()`

Comment: `sub("^(RNDM.*)\\..*$", "\\1", dfrm$text.NANA)`.

Comment: The Female/Male information is also included in the same column, and the number of spaces in between vary from row to row. Sometimes it is 1 space, sometimes it is 2

Comment: @RuiBarradas, this got me `"Female RNDM_MXN95.tif"  "Male RNDM_QOS38.tif"    "Female  RNDM_WQW90.tif"` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just want to remove the file extension? Use [`file_path_sans_ext`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/tools/html/fileutils.html):

```
dfrm$BARCODE = file_path_sans_ext(dfrm$text.NANA)
```

If there’s more stuff in front, you can use the following regular expression to extract just the suffix:

```
dfrm$BARCODE = stringr::str_match(dfrm$text.NANA, '(RNDM_.*)\\.tif')[, 2]
```

Note that I’m using the {stringr} package here because the base R functions for extracting regex matches are terrible. Nobody uses them.

I strongly recommend *against* using `strsplit` here because it’s underspecified: from reading the code it’s absolutely not clear what the purpose of that code is. Write code that is self-explanatory, not code that requires explanation in a comment.

Comment: I also want to remove the Male&Female, and there is an arbitrary amount of spaces (sometimes 1, sometimes 2) between the gender info and the barcode

Comment: Ah I see, I hadn’t noticed that was in the same column. Let me fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can use sapply() and strsplit to do it easy, let me show you:

`sapply(strsplit(dfrm$text.NANA, "_"),"[", 1)`

That should work.

Edit:

`sapply(strsplit(x, "[ .]+"),"[", 2)`

Comment: This got me `"Female RNDM"  "Male RNDM"    "Female  RNDM" "Male  RNDM"`

Comment: i missed the female or male

Comment: The updated answer got me `"RNDM" "RNDM" "RNDM" "RNDM"` :D

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(x, "[ .]+"),"[", 2)` worked, thanks! But, can you briefly explain what does what? I don't understand how to use the `[`, `]` and the `+`. Is this Perl?

Comment: there you can delimit how do you want to split if i got for example: X_asas.asdas and you put [_.] you will separate you string in 3 parts then you choose what part do you want

Comment: Don’t string-quote R names (`'['`), use backtick quotes instead (`\`[\``); the fact that R even *allows* string quotes here is a glaring mistake in the language that leads to unnecessary confusion.

Comment: thanks for the explanation konrad now i understand better